# How do I capture the String generated from com.sun.mail.iap.Argument?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to debug my custom javamail `IMAPCommand`s.

In the process of constructing the command to send to the IMAP server, I do something like this:

```
public Object doCommand(IMAPProtocol p) throws ProtocolException {
Argument args = new Argument();

Argument sortCrit = new Argument();
sortCrit.writeString("REVERSE");
sortCrit.writeString("DATE");
args.writeArgument(sortCrit);

args.writeString("UTF-8");

Argument from1 = new Argument();
from1.writeString("FROM");
from1.writeString(searchFrom.get(0));

Argument from2 = new Argument();
from2.writeString("FROM");
from2.writeString(searchFrom.get(1));

fromArg.writeString("OR");
fromArg.writeArgument(from1);
fromArg.writeArgument(from2);

args.writeArgument(fromArg);

Response[] r = p.command("UID SORT", args);
Response response = r[r.length - 1];
[...]
}
```

I want to log (say, to stderr) what will be sent to the server with `p.command`. How do I do that?

Comment: I know I can construct a new Protocol instance on the fly and hand it an OutputStream to write to. But that feels waay to complicated.

Comment: And no, applying Wireshark or the like is not an option as this an outbound, encrypted imap connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call session.setDebug(true) and you'll get an entire protocol trace on System.out.  That will show you what you're actually sending.

Comment: While Andreas_D's suggestions works just fine, this is what I'm looking for. One line to solve it all (even redirectible to a Stream of my choice). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance it looks like the `Protocol` implementation has some debugging capabilities. [Create a `Protocol` with streams](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/javax.mail/com.springsource.javax.mail/1.4.0/com/sun/mail/iap/Protocol.java#Protocol.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.InputStream,java.io.OutputStream,boolean%29) and pass `true` for the `debug` argument.

Then you should see the input and output for this command dumped to `System.out`.

Comment: That's what I thought to be "waay to complicated" ;) But since there really seems to be no better alternative I'm accepting the answer.